# if else statement in php not displaying data

Tags: php, html

i have a website in which i display some value from database, i have used one if else statement to display an html section if the value is true in database, i have used the following code:

```html
<?php if ($re['country']= "USA"){ echo
 '<div id="tabs1-css">

<iframe width="100%" height="650" src="files.html"></iframe>
 </div>';

 else {echo "NO Samples";}
}
 ?>
```

can anyone please tell me what wrong i did in my code

Comment: What is the expected result?  What is the actual result?

Comment: `$re['country']= "USA"`  This is an assignment, not an equality check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shoulde be like this. You forgot close brace of if statement. Also as  said by user2342558 I add = in if statement.

```
<?php if ($re['country']== "USA"){ echo
 '<div id="tabs1-css">

<iframe width="100%" height="650" src="files.html"></iframe>
 </div>';
}
 else {echo "NO Samples";}

 ?>
```

Comment: You also added a missed `=`

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm adding.

Comment: where did i forget to close

Answer (score 1):

You are [assigning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) with the `=` instead of [comparing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) with the `==`, so try this code:

```
<?php if ($re['country'] == "USA"){ echo
```

Also, adjust the `{` and `}`:

```
<?php
if ($re['country'] == 'USA') {
    echo '<div id="tabs1-css">
    <iframe width="100%" height="650" src="files.html"></iframe>
    </div>';
}
else {
    echo "NO Samples";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

check the brackets:

```
<?php if ($re['country'] == "USA"){ echo
 '<div id="tabs1-css">

<iframe width="100%" height="650" src="files.html"></iframe>
 </div>';

 }else {echo "NO Samples";}
 ?>
```